# If I use qt, Can I use c++ to implement all functions in qml samples

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I like clion, but clion hasn't support qml yet, so I hope use pure c++ to dev my personal app.

- can i use all qt5 ui features with pure c++?
- what about android or ios platform, can i also do that?

Answer (score 1):

> can i use all qt5 ui features with pure c++?

Yes, if You're speaking about QtWidgets. You cannot use QML drawing methods, scened etc from c++ directly.

> what about android or ios platform, can i also do that?

QtWidgets are ported to android, but better to use QML there, because widgets are too desktop-centric. Yes, nokia (and then digia) made *some* work to fix it but it's still (Feb 2016) *not enogh* .

I recommend You to use QML in Your clion or every other favourite IDE with custom buildscript (qmake && make && [run application]).